# Chamar variável PHP dentro de uma função Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Dentro do .js do NivoSlider, tenho a seguinte linha que chama as duas setinhas do slider (esquerda e direita):

```
slider.append('<div class="nivo-directionNav"><a class="nivo-prevNav"><img class="seta-esquerda" src="document.write('<?php echo $imagens_links_base . $imagens_links['seta-esquerda'] ;?>');" /></a><a class="nivo-nextNav"><img class="seta-direita" src="document.write('<?php echo $imagens_links_base . $imagens_links['seta-direita'] ;?>');'" /></a></div>');
```

As partes abaixo é onde eu tento, sem sucesso, exibir uma variável criada em PHP na página principal:

```
<?php echo $imagens_links_base . $imagens_links['seta-esquerda'] ;?>

<?php echo $imagens_links_base . $imagens_links['seta-direita'] ;?>
```

Como eu posso acertar isso?

Comment: Se entendi bem, se o teu ficheiro tem a extensão `.JS` duvido que tenhas o servidor preparado para o executar como um PHP de forma a que o código entre `<?php ... ?>` funcione.

Comment: Sim, o ficheiro tem a extensão .js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solução teria que ser um pouco mais elaborada.

### Na página principal:

Ponha a parte PHP que processa as variáveis no começo do script, e acrescente algo deste tipo **na parte PHP**:

```
$esquerda = $imagens_links_base . $imagens_links['seta-esquerda'];
$direita  = $imagens_links_base . $imagens_links['seta-direita'];
```

E, **na parte HTML** que chama o JS anterior, modificado:

Supondo que o original seja assim:

```
<script src="/scripts/meuScript.js"></script>
```

Você muda para

```
<?php
   // notar que mudamos o .js pra .php:
   echo '<script src="scripts/meuScript.php?esquerda=';
   echo urlencode( $esquerda ) . '"&direita="' . urlencode( $direita );
   echo '"></script>';
?>
```

Notar que a ordem do código neste caso é importante. Seu PHP tem que produzir as variáveis corretas antes desse `<script>`, o que pode dar algum trabalho dependendo de como seu código se encontra hoje.

### no seu JavaScript:

Primeiro, renomeie o script de .js para .php, para que ele seja processado no servidor.

Acrescente estas linhas logo no começo do script:

```
<?php
    $esquerda = $_GET['esquerda'];
    $direita  = $_GET['direita' ];
?>
```

Estas linhas vão extrair os caminhos montados pela página principal, e colocá-las nas variávers `$esquerda` e `$direita`, para facilitar a parte seguinte.

Aí modifique as linhas mencionadas desta forma:

```
slider.append('<div class="nivo-directionNav">
   <a class="nivo-prevNav"><img class="seta-esquerda" src="<?php echo $esquerda; ?>" /></a>
   <a class="nivo-nextNav"><img class="seta-direita"  src="<?php echo $direita; ?>" /></a>
</div>');
```

### Breve explicação:

O JavaScript roda no navegador, e o PHP roda no servidor. São linguagens e conceitos completamente separados.

A proposta de solução faz o seguinte: primeiro, na página principal, enviamos os caminhos todos processados pelo PHP para o arquivo JS, como parte do URL.

Em seguida, ao mudar o nome do arquivo JS para PHP, fazemos com que ele seja processado no servidor, e as variáveis enviadas na URL serão inseridas na parte em JS, e depois enviado o resultado para o navegador, com o caminho correto já fazendo parte do source, como se tivesse sido digitado. O navegador nem toma conhecimento do PHP.

**Importante:** com certeza tem mil maneiras mais elegantes de se resolver este problema, a intenção maior da resposta foi "forçar a barra" para a coisa funcionar da maneira que você está imaginando> Agora, esquecer essa solução e repensar a coisa na ordem certa e separar as tarefas de cada linguagem seria o caminho mais correto.

Comment: Cara, extremamente didático, muito obrigado. Vou testar e posto aqui depois o resultado.