# Como usar a sintaxe C# no 'onclick'

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, razor

Declarei uma variável na *view*:

```
@{
   int index = 0;
}
```

E quero alterá-la através de um `onclick`:

```
@for (var b = 0; b < cont; b++)
{                                               
    <li> <a onclick="@(Index = b)">Endereço @(b + 1)</a> </li>
}
```

Comment: Cara, o que vc precisa fazer exatamente? Pq vc deseja mudar o valor da variavel? Acredito que sua solução está confusa e pode ser melhorada, dependendo do que vc precisar..

Comment: Porque logo embaixo eu tenho isso:
<input name="NMLOGCRE" value="@(Model.Enderecos[Index].Split('*')[1])" >

Comment: @AndréNakamura A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Você não pode fazer isto diretamente, o que roda no cliente nada tem a ver com o que roda no servidor, são bases de código diferentes, são até linguagens diferentes. É como você querer apagar uma mensagem de e-mail do seu amigo, mesmo que permitisse, seria inseguro.

O que pode ser feito é mandar o cliente solicitar ao servidor fazer o que deseja. Tem que mandar uma mensagem pelo navegador e o código no servidor fará o que deve.

É possível fazer isto de diversas formas, uma delas é com [AJAX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3167/101), o que [provavelmente é o mais adequado neste caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91147/101). Já [respondi um exemplo para PHP, mas no JavaScript é a mesma coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90095/101).

[Mais sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39583/101).