# Valores em php exportando para javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um código com php e javascript, gostaria de saber como posso utilizar o valor da variável do meu código em php dentro do java script.
Segue o código:

```js
var teste = "<?php echo $teste; ?>";
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'column',
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 6,
      beta: 16,
      depth: 100,
      viewDistance: 200
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Clientes'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Gráfico demonstrativo'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      depth: 25
    }
  },
  series: [{
    "colorByPoint": true,
    data: [{
      "name": "Coluna 1",
      "y": teste.9,
      "drilldown": "Coluna "
    }, {
      "name": "Coluna 2",
      "y": 106.4,
      "drilldown": "Coluna 2"
    }, {
      "name": "Coluna 3",
      "y": 1000.5,
      "drilldown": "Coluna 3"
    }, {
      "name": "Coluna 4",
      "y": 144.0,
      "drilldown": "Coluna 4"
    }]
  }]
});

function showValues() {
  $('#alpha-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha);
  $('#beta-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.beta);
  $('#depth-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.depth);
}


$('#sliders input').on('input change', function() {
  chart.options.chart.options3d[this.id] = parseFloat(this.value);
  showValues();
  chart.redraw(false);
});

showValues();
```

```css
#container,
#sliders {
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#container {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<?php $teste="20"; ?>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="sliders">
</div>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Valor do php no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197975/valor-do-php-no-javascript)

Comment: Eu vi essa pergunta, porém, o método de lá não deu certo

Comment: Se o arquivo que contém o código em `javascript` for `.html` ou `.js` você não irá conseguir usar a variável. Para usar as variáveis e códigos em php, o arquivo tem que ser `.php`.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Igualar variável php a uma variável javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25136/igualar-vari%c3%a1vel-php-a-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-javascript) | [Variável PHP no JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318715/5878) | [Passar variável php para javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58958/5878) | [Chamar variável PHP dentro de uma função Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39583/5878)

Comment: Esse assunto é bastante recorrente aqui no site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bphp%5d%20%5bjs%5d%20vari%C3%A1vel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite, verifique se você esta atribuindo a variável do PHP antes do seu echo no javascript, acho que você não esta fazendo isso.

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php 
    $teste = 20;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exemplo</title>
    </head>
    <script>
        var teste = <?= $teste ?>;
        console.log(teste);
    </script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Certifique-se de colocar `;` apos declarar e atribuir a variável no javascript.
Note que alguns servidores não estão habilitados a executar a saída `<?= var ?>` você pode usar `<?php echo var; ?>` apesar de ser menos elegante.

Lembre-se PHP é executado no servidor e javascript no cliente.

Comment: Excelente! deu mto certo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

você deve dar echo no html e com jquery pega esse valor 
exemplo :

```
<div id="container" id="<?= $teste="20"; ?>"></div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        var teste = $("#conteiner").attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Mto obrigado pela resposta. Bom saber que existem outras formas de se chegar ao mesmo resultado.